# Best approach to connect in mysql local with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, web-deployment

I have a docker image of apache and another one with my database (mysql).

My local database has a diffent string of connection that my production database. So every time I will deploy my application, I need to chance the credentials to the production credentials.

What is the best practice to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make the connection string a configuration option. You can set it as environment variable in the container and the app can read it from the env variable.